# Paste emoji icon in textarea

Tags: html, textarea, paste

I created a `<textarea>`on my website where I can write text into then click on a button and that text will be saved in the database.

The problem is that textarea can't recognize icon like . If I write :

```
abcdefg
```

Only "abcd" will be saved in the database. Can someone tell me why and how to fix? Thanks alot.

Comment: Seethis [link](http://character-code.com/emoticons-html-codes.php)

Comment: Sr I don't see how that can help :(

Comment: He is trying to say to you that you can not save an emoticon on the database `as it is`, and pointed you to the site where you can get the codes realtieve to the emoticons you need.

Comment: Exactly... @Franco